# GCC LLVM assemble on different CPU arches

Tags: gcc, assembly, llvm

Hi there Im trying to understand more abt the compilers;
when using gcc -S 
it generates a .s file like

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.macosx_version_min 10, 12
.globl  _main
.p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
.cfi_startproc
## BB#0:

pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
.cfi_offset %rbp, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
.cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
movb    $0, %al
callq   _printf
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
movl    %ecx, %eax
addq    $16, %rsp
popq    %rbp
retq
.cfi_endproc

.section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
.asciz  "Hello World!\n"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

my question is : is this .s assemble file generated based on specific cpu arch like x86 or its cpu arch irrelevant？ 
if its irrelevant, will we add cpu config like ARMv7s in command "gcc -O " ?

Question 2:
llvm-gcc -S generated code is pretty much different from a assemble language; is that a cpu arch irrelevant LLVM IR language? and the LLVM backend handle the rest of jobs to convert it to specific cpu arches?

many thanks

Comment: Q1 yes that's architecture specific (x86 in your example) Q2 yes, LLVM IR is portable

Comment: great and quick answer, thanks a lot Jester

Comment: To clarify: llvm ir can be reasonably portable, but in practice with C like languages it isn't portable across architectures.